# How to link to nested routes in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Currently I am using the following code for my application.

```js
const {
  Router,
  Route,
  IndexRoute,
  Redirect,
  Link,
  IndexLink,
  hashHistory
} = ReactRouter

var App = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
   return (
     <div>
       <h1>My Application</h1>
        <div><Link to="/levelone/1">Go to One</Link></div>
        <div><Link to="/levelone/1/leveltwo/5">Go to Three</Link></div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var Index = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
   return (
      <div>
       <h2>This is index route</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var LevelOne =  React.createClass({
  render : function() {
   return (
     <div>
       <h2>This is LevelOne</h2>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var LevelTwo = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
   return (
     <div>
       <h2>This is LevelTwo</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
})


var routes= (
 <Route path= "/" component={App}>
     <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
     <Route path="/levelone/:id" component={LevelOne}>
            <Route path="/leveltwo/:idd" component={LevelTwo}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={ hashHistory } routes={routes}></Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.1.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router@3.0.0/umd/ReactRouter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="app"><div>
```

In the above code I am linking to `/levelone/1/leveltwo/5` from the component `App` which is not working and is showing the error `[react-router] Location "/levelone/1/leveltwo/5" did not match any routes`.

But if I put the link inside the component `LevelOne` like in the following snippet the link will point to LevelTwo just like i want

```
var LevelOne =  React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>This is LevelOne</h2>
                <div><Link to="leveltwo/5">Go to LevelTwo</Link></div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

What should I do if I want to link to LevelTwo from the outermost component ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When nesting routes, be careful when you're intending to actually use relative paths to not use absolute paths. Your route definition

`<Route path="/leveltwo/:idd" component={LevelTwo}/>`

should instead be:

`<Route path="leveltwo/:idd" component={LevelTwo}/>`

The reason why `<div><Link to="leveltwo/5">Go to LevelTwo</Link></div>` was working is because `<Link>` only supports absolute paths (see above) and was actually pointing to `/leveltwo/5` and the route definition you had initially was defined with an absolute path. So although the code ran, it wasn't actually running the way you had intended.

Comment: No offence, but I think you misread the question. He said that putting `<Link to="leveltwo/5">Go to LevelTwo</Link>` inside the `LevelOne` component worked for him, whereas putting the absolute URL inside the outermost `App` component didn't. You can see it when you run the snippet

Comment: You're right, thanks for that. I clearly should be in bed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you have a `/` in the subroute definition.

Just change this :

`<Route path="/leveltwo/:idd" component={LevelTwo}/>`

to

`<Route path="leveltwo/:idd" component={LevelTwo}/>`

The following is the working snippet

```js
const {
  Router,
  Route,
  IndexRoute,
  Redirect,
  Link,
  IndexLink,
  hashHistory
} = ReactRouter

var App = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
   return (
     <div>
       <h1>My Application</h1>
        <div><Link to="/levelone/1">Go to One</Link></div>
        <div><Link to="levelone/1/leveltwo/5">Go to Three</Link></div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var Index = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
   return (
      <div>
       <h2>This is index route</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var LevelOne =  React.createClass({
  render : function() {
   return (
     <div>
       <h2>This is LevelOne</h2>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var LevelTwo = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
   return (
     <div>
       <h2>This is LevelTwo</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
})


var routes= (
 <Route path= "/" component={App}>
     <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
     <Route path="/levelone/:id" component={LevelOne}>
            <Route path="leveltwo/:idd" component={LevelTwo}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={ hashHistory } routes={routes}></Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.1.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router@3.0.0/umd/ReactRouter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
```